# How to create a circular geometry in python using rectangle patches

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a circular geometry in python using rectangular patches, so I want to create a rectangular patch, which when I looked at the documentation can be created by

```
rectangle = plt.Rectangle((x,y), width, height)
plt.gca().add_patch(rectangle)
```

and then I want to place that is a circular manner, such that it creates what looks like a detector, with the rectangles as "detector blocks". How can I achieve that? Thank you

Final result should look like the image shown
[Final Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMcrz.jpg)

Comment: Can you post a picture how the result should look like? For me it is unclear what you mean by "detector blocks" and what you're hoping to get as a final image.

Comment: Please check the edited post, I have attached the image of the final result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a figure with N rectangles, divide a circle evenly into N parts, so into angles of `2pi/N`. The x and y are the sine and cosine of the subsequent angles multiplied by the radius of the inner circle.

The rectangles themselves need to be rotated by the mean angle of the segment. And -90 degrees extra to have the width perpendicular to the radius.

Note that sine and cosine operate on angles in radians, while the rotation of the rectangles is expressed in degrees.

Because patches don't automatically set the plot limits, they need to be set explicitly.

Here is some code to get you started:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
width = 6
height = 4
num_rect = 12
r = width / 2 / np.sin(np.pi / num_rect)
for i in range(num_rect):
    theta = 2 * np.pi * (i + 0.5) / num_rect
    x = r * np.cos(theta)
    y = r * np.sin(theta)
    rectangle = plt.Rectangle((x, y), width, height, angle=360 * i / num_rect - 90,
                              edgecolor='dodgerblue', facecolor=plt.cm.rainbow(i / num_rect), alpha=.5)
    ax.add_patch(rectangle)

d = (r + height) * 1.1
ax.set_xlim(-d, d)
ax.set_ylim(-d, d)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]